# How to optimise code in react "if statement"

Tags: reactjs

In my project I have about 200line of if statement like `if (fieldnameA == "A" && fieldnameB == "A") {return...}`
and there is only one situation that this statement work, I mean it always return differed value, and never work 2 condition at once.
I started thinking about optimise this code because it is in useMemo hook, so I think it is a good practice, but what if I start using Ternary Operators?
like:

```
fieldnameA == "A" && fieldnameB == "A" ? something : fieldnameA == "A" && fieldnameB == "B" ? something another : fieldnameA == "A" && fieldnameB == "C" (...)
```

It is similar to switch statement and stop checking after find a correct statement.
but I do not know that so long code can be

Comment: Chaining any more than a couple of ternary operators is generally pretty horrible to read, I would always avoid that if you can. Can you try to give an example of your current code? It's a bit difficult to understand what you are asking at the moment.

Comment: It sounds like you're solving a problem that doesn't exist. When optimization comes at the cost of readable code, you should really pause and evaluate how much that optimization is worth.. It usually isn't the right option. Focus on writing the clearest code possible (that usually will never include a ternary that looks like that...)

Comment: Adding to the above, there seems to be just lesser code and no real optimization when you compare the above to basic if else, else-if.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, it is not really good idea to use ternary operator more than one time. It is not optimising, but it decreases readability and next time when you will debug, then you will have to pay more efforts to understand what it is going on here :).

What you can do is to write more readable conditions wrapped in methods.

Let me show an example:

```
if (person.name === anotherPerson.name)
```

to:

```
const hasTheSameName = (personOne, personTwo) => 
    (personOne.name === personTwo.name)
```

and your `if` statement would like this:

```
if (hasTheSameName(personOne, personTwo) &&
    // ... the other code is omitted for the brevity)
```